# How Do I Access My PostgreSQL Database From a Clock Process Heroku Flask?

Tags: python, database, flask, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a [custom clock process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes#custom-clock-processes) running in Heroku that sends emails to my users every day.

The problem is I need to access the users from my database and I don't have access to my flask app context since it's running in a different process.

I've been googling for the past hour with no luck so here I am. I tried importing current_app from flask but it gave me this:

```
Job "check_if_users_did_devotions (trigger: cron[minute='*'], next run at: 2020-07-07 12:49:00 CDT)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\smith\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\smith\PycharmProjects\MyProject\MyProject\Tasks.py", line 11, in send_email
    print(current_app)
  File "C:\Users\smith\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 366, in <lambda>
    __str__ = lambda x: str(x._get_current_object())
  File "C:\Users\smith\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\Users\smith\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 52, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I think I might need to connect to the database in the clock process separately but I don't know if that would cause issues having two separate connections to the same database. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what does "I need to access the users from my database and I don't have access to my flask app context since it's running in a different process" mean? Why would you need to connect to a running Flask instance?

Comment: @Chris Meaning a separate process of python designated as a "clock process" (This is how Heroku talks about it). Basically I need to know if it's okay to access my Postgres database from a separate process.

Comment: I've used Heroku for years and never come across the term "clock process". Do you mean a background process? Or a scheduled process / cronjob? And I'm still unclear about why this has anything to do with your database. All modern client-server databases can handle multiple connections.

Comment: @Chris Sorry here is the article I am referencing https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes. I'm scheduling background tasks that I don't want running on my main thread, and I need variables that are in my database. Let me know if this clears it up for you.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Thanks for the reference. Does your clock process code know how to get whatever you need from your database? (Or, maybe, more accurately: does whatever your clock process needs to _kick off_ know how to do that.) Have you tried just... running it? It should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, I ended just coding it that way. It does run but I was worried that it would run into issues if my main process tried editing the database at the same time.

Comment: If you're doing something really weird, _maybe_, but as I said above modern databases are designed for concurrent access. You've tagged this with [tag:heroku-postgres], and [PostgreSQL uses](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MVCC) [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) to ensure that every connection to the database gets a consistent view of it. You should be fine. I guess maybe this should be an answer? I'll add one and expand on this a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All modern client-server databases that I'm aware of have strategies for handling multiple connections. A very common strategy, [Multiversion Concurrency Control (MVCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), [is used by PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MVCC) and many other databases:

> When an MVCC database needs to update a piece of data, it will not overwrite the original data item with new data, but instead creates a newer version of the data item. Thus there are multiple versions stored. The version that each transaction sees depends on the isolation level implemented. The most common isolation level implemented with MVCC is snapshot isolation. With snapshot isolation, a transaction observes a state of the data as when the transaction started.
>
> MVCC provides [point-in-time consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_consistency#Point-in-time_consistency) views. Read transactions under MVCC typically use a timestamp or transaction ID to determine what state of the DB to read, and read these versions of the data. Read and write transactions are thus [isolated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) from each other without any need for locking. However, despite locks being unnecessary, they are used by some MVCC databases such as Oracle. Writes create a newer version, while concurrent reads access an older version.

Basically, each connection you make will have a consistent view of the database. Unless you're doing something *really* weird, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the scheduled function depends on an application context, yet is running in a separate process from your application.

You can create and push a separate application context to your clock processes.

Within your `clock.py` script, you'll want to create an app, and pass it to any functions that require an application context to function.

Then, push the context from the passed app within your function.

```
# clock.py
app = create_app()

def foo(app):
    with app.app_context():
        # ... work that requires context

scheduler.add_job(tester, 'cron', [app], hour=12)
```